# Options not showing in the Manage section blade in Azure App Registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I tried to select the option "App Roles" in the Manage section from the menu on the left but is not showing.

[image: Azure App Registration]

Comment: b2c does not support approle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD B2C does not support `appRoles`.

Comment: Good catch on Azure AD B2C from the screenshot :).

Comment: Yes as said by @carl Application roles are not currently supported in Azure AD B2C. You may want to use Azure feedback portal to add this request or vote for an existing one.

Comment: Thanks! I was not able to find that in the documentation easily, thank you

Comment: @JCH97  If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. :)